# Using two variables to create a jQuery object

Tags: jquery, variables, object

Never ran into this situation before and now I am having trouble accomplishing this.

I basically want this:

```
$(cardMonth).prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'></option>");
$(cardYear).prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'></option>");
```

To be something like this:

```
$(cardMonth, cardYear).prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'></option>");
```

Comment: And it doesnt work? Have you tried it? But what are `cardMonth` and `cardYear`? Id's or classnames? So its either `$('#cardMonth, #cardYear')` or `$('.cardMonth, .cardYear')`

Comment: They are variables. They work fine separated, but trying to use them in the same line does not work.

Comment: And where and how did you define the variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(cardMonth).add(cardYear).prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'></option>");
```

Alternatively:

```
var els[0] = cardMonth;
var els[1] = cardYear;
$(els).prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'></option>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need jQuery.merge(), http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge/:

```
$.merge($(cardMonth), $(cardYear)).prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'></option>");
```